# MySQL: I need to return rows according to certain conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-order-by, mysql-5.7

I have a 3 tables: work, recording, release

1 work can have multiple recordings and 1 recording appears in only 1 release

**TABLE: work**

```
+---------+-----------+
| work_id | name      |
+---------+-----------+
| 1       | Hello     | 
| 3       | Luna      | 
| 4       | Feel good | 
| 5       | My self   | 
+---------+-----------+
```

**TABLE: recording**

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| recording_id | work_id | release_id | name        | is_art | is_vid |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 45           | 1       | 45         | Hello4      | 1      | 0      |
| 78           | 3       | 67         | Luna5       | 1      | 0      |
| 23           | 5       | 128        | My self (r) | 1      | 0      |
| 95           | 5       | 156        | My self II  | 1      | 0      |
| 17           | 4       | 67         | Luna67      | 1      | 0      |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**TABLE: release**

```
+--------------------------------------------+
| release_id | name    | year | month | day  |
+--------------------------------------------+
| 45         | Yo      | 1998 | 12    | NULL |
| 67         | Testing | 1967 | 3     | 3    |
| 128        | Maybe   | 2018 | 10    | 21   |
| 156        | Again   | 2018 | 10    | NULL |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

Basically, for each `work`, I want to return the `recording` where `is_art = 1` and `is_vid = 0` AND were the `release` is the oldest (oldest year, month and date). I could be that a `recording` `release` can have the same `year`, `month` and `day`. In that case I guess I need to find a unique identifier, so ill go with latest `release_id`

result set should look like:

```
+---------+---------------------------------------+
| work_id | name      | recording_id | name       |
+---------+---------------------------------------+
| 1       | Hello     | 45           | Hello4     |
| 3       | Luna      | 78           | Luna5      |
| 4       | Feel good | 17           | Luna67     |
| 5       | My self   | 23           | My self (r)|
+---------+---------------------------------------+
```

So far, I created this query, but, honestly, as a newbie, I know its all wrong. It return duplicate rows. I fell like I need to use `group by` and subqueries but after 2 days of searching and testing stuff, I cannot create a solution... im going crazy

SAMPLE DATA 1

```
| work_id | work_name           | recording_id | release_id | rec_name                                            | year | month | day |
|---------|---------------------|--------------|------------|-----------------------------------------------------|------|-------|-----|
|     201 | Me ha dicho la luna |          253 |          5 | Me ha dicho la luna                                 | 1998 |     4 |  22 |
|     201 | Me ha dicho la luna |          579 |        528 | Me ha dicho la luna (Moonlight Radio Edit)          | 1998 |       |     |
|     201 | Me ha dicho la luna |          580 |        528 | Me ha dicho la luna (Luna llena Ambience Mix)       | 1998 |       |     |
|     201 | Me ha dicho la luna |          581 |        528 | Me ha dicho la luna (Extended Callejuela's Version) | 1998 |       |     |
|     201 | Me ha dicho la luna |          582 |        528 | Me ha dicho la luna (Stoned Baby Free Version)      | 1998 |       |     |
|     201 | Me ha dicho la luna |          252 |          1 | Me ha dicho la luna (con Chayanne)                  | 2006 |       |     |
```

SAMPLE DATA 2

```
| work_id | work_name  | recording_id | release_id | rec_name                                                | year | month | day |
|---------|------------|--------------|------------|---------------------------------------------------------|------|-------|-----|
|     401 | Si amanece |          397 |         26 | Si amanece                                              | 1978 |     7 |   1 |
|     401 | Si amanece |          634 |        309 | Si amanece                                              | 1978 |     7 |   1 |
|     401 | Si amanece |          396 |        257 | Si amanece (con el Mariachi Oro y Plata de Pepe Chávez) | 1979 |       |     |
|     401 | Si amanece |          564 |        188 | Si amanece                                              | 2001 |       |     |
|     401 | Si amanece |          394 |        213 | Si amanece                                              | 2001 |       |     |
|     401 | Si amanece |          395 |          1 | Si amanece                                              | 2006 |       |     |
|     401 | Si amanece |          638 |        295 | Si amanece                                              |      |       |     |
```

Comment: In your expected result, how does row no.3 get the `recording_id = 128` and `name= My self II`?

Comment: @tcadidot0 You are right to ask, coz I've made a mistake on my example. It's fix now. It should return `recording_id = 23` and `name=My self (r)`

Comment: @Marco, I some confused by NULL values in release.day field. How I can guess oldest value with NULL day?

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev That's a good point. Sometimes I don't have the day or month or even year of the `release` album.

Comment: So, you need to decide is  NULL value older or newer then other value with number

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev I agree. If I have a `release` dated `2018-10-21` and another `release` dated `2018-10-NULL` the oldest will be the `release` dated `2018-10-21` because at least there is a complete date. So, I guess a `NULL` value could be consider as newer then other value with number. If there are 2 `release` with same date, I will use the oldest `release_id` to pick one.

Comment: "1 recording appears in only 1 release" -- do you mean `1:1`?  Or `many:1`?  If it is many:1, add a row to the sample data as an example.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Comment: A "basically" or "essentially" or "in other words" that doesn't introduce or summarize a clear, precise & full description that you also give just means "unclearly". Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @RickJames im using 5.7.28 and I mean 1 recording appears in 1 release and 1 release can appear in m recordings.I've added a row to the sample db

Comment: It would help if the release date were a _single DATE_ column, not two separate dates.

Comment: You say "for each work", yet the desired output does not include work #4.  What am I missing?

Comment: @RickJames The thing is that im compiling album releases from an artist and I don't have the exact release date for all the albums. Sometimes I have a complete date, sometimes, just the year, and sometimes the year and month. Also, it's true that work#4 should be in my example... i've edited my question to add a row to the sample and forgot to also add it to result set... I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @Marco - Should a missing component of a date be considered high?  Or low?  Ed's answer treats it as "low".  But your answer treats it as "high".

Comment: @Marco - It might help if you had a couple more records -- to deal with the case where the dates are identical, and the query needs to resort to the `release_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to get the 'right' answer:

```
-- Query 1
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (
    new_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
)
SELECT  w.work_id,
        w.name AS work_name,
        rec.recording_id,
        rec.release_id,
        rec.name AS rec_name,
        year, month, day
    FROM work AS w
    JOIN recording AS rec ON rec.work_id = w.work_id
    JOIN releaset AS rel ON rel.release_id = rec.release_id
    WHERE is_art = 1
      AND is_vid = 0
    ORDER BY work_id, year, month, day, release_id;

-- Query 2
SELECT work_id, work_name, recording_id, rec_name
    FROM ( SELECT MIN(new_id) AS first_id FROM t
               GROUP BY work_id, year, month, day, release_id ) AS x
    JOIN t ON t.new_id = x.first_id;
```

Unfortunately, it will fail on some versions.

- MariaDB 10.2+ will not complain of `Can't reopen table: 't'`.  There are two workarounds:  Make `t` not `TEMPORARY` or copy the temp table into another temp table.
- MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB 10.2+ can use a `WITH`, to effectively use the temp table repeatedly.  A potential issue, though is the need to add an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column to the temp table.

OK, here's how to bypass the "reopen" problem:

```
-- Query 3
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE x
    SELECT MIN(new_id) AS first_id FROM t
        GROUP BY work_id;

-- Query 4
SELECT work_id, work_name, recording_id, rec_name
    FROM x
    JOIN t ON t.new_id = x.first_id;
```

Then use queries 1,3,4.

Comment: Did some testing and it's really fast. But I notice that it returns the wrong `release` in cases where the date is null. I put some REAL data (sample 1, 2) so you can see. For example, in SAMPLE DATA 1, it should return 253, but it returns 579. In SAMPLE DATA 2, it should return 397, but it returns 638. I hope this real data helps. I should have put real data sooner.

Comment: I may tackle it again, but first I need to know your rule about null date parts.  That is, is [1998, null, null] older or newer than [1998, 4, 28]?

Comment: [1998, 4, 28] is older than [1998, null, null] because at least the date is more complete. [2001, null, null] is older than [null, null, null]...

Comment: @Marco - those are inconsistent.  What about just the `day` being missing?

Comment: I guess what i'm trying to say is that Im prioritizing dates that are the most complete. If for the same `work_id` I have [1998, 4 ,28] and [1998, null, null] then I'm prioritizing [1998, 4, 28] because at least I have a year, month and a day. If for the same `work_id` I have [2001, null, null] and [null, null, null] then im prioritizing [2001,null,null] coz at least I have a year

Comment: @Marco - Alas, my code took the simple road of letting `NULLs` being _less than_ non-nulls in the `ORDER BY`.  May need some coalesces like Ed did, but possibly even messier since NULL needs to be "high" in some cases and "low" in others.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a query that produces the expected results for your sample data:

```
select
    w.work_id,
    w.name work_name,
    r.recording_id,
    r.name recording_name
from work w
inner join recording r 
    on r.recording_id = (
        select r1.recording_id 
        from recording r1 
        inner join releases l1 on l1.release_id = r1.release_id
        where r1.work_id = w.work_id and r1.is_art = 1 and r1.is_vid = 0
        order by -l1.year desc, -l1.month desc, -l1.day desc, r1.release_id desc
        limit 1
    )
```

This works by joining the `work` table with `recording`, using a correlated subquery to select the correct row. From your sample data and results, it appears that you want to put `null`s first when sorting the rows order: this is not the default behavior in MySQL, so we use a trick that consists in ordering by `- <column_name> desc` (which puts `null`s first while honoring the ascending sort).

Note: `release` is a [reserved word in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html), so I named that table `releases` instead (otherwise, you need to enclose it with backticks).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=31422e993bb7f52c5209082186beace5)**:

```
work_id | work_name | recording_id | recording_name
------: | :-------- | -----------: | :-------------
      1 | Hello     |           45 | Hello4        
      3 | Luna      |           78 | Luna5         
      5 | My self   |           23 | My self (r)
```

---

Alternatively, if you are running MySQL 8.0, you use `row_number()` to identify the correct recording. Depending on your dataset, this might, or might not perform better:

```
select work_id, work_name, recording_id, recording_name
from (
    select
        w.work_id,
        w.name work_name,
        r.recording_id,
        r.name recording_name,
        row_number() over(
            partition by r.work_id 
            order by -l.year desc, -l.month desc, -l.day desc, r.release_id desc
        ) rn
    from work w
    inner join recording r 
        on r.work_id = w.work_id
        and r.is_art = 1
        and r.is_vid = 0
    inner join releases l 
        on l.release_id = r.release_id
) t
where rn = 1
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6745bfa113a10643cf89068dc95daede)** (same results as above)

Comment: Performance is likely to be terrible if you more than a few rows in each table.  (No, I don't see a better solution.)

Comment: @RickJames: yes, possibly... I just added another query that uses `row_number()` to select the correct release. This might, or might not, give better performance...

Comment: This does it! I must agree, it's a little bit slow  but not too much coz my db is pretty small. On average it takes 116ms (0.11 seconds) to run the query. It's ok since there is no better solution.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` is not efficient.  Anyway, it is not available in 5.7.

Comment: Thank you @GMB This works perfectly, but a little bit slow. I do appreciate all of your effort.

Answer (score 1):

getting the latest `recording` per `work_id` you can use aggregation function `max()` followed by `group by` clause.

```
select w.work_id, w.name, r.recording_Id, r.name, 
     max(cast(concat(coalesce(year, '1000'), coalesce(month, '01'), coalesce(day, '01')) as date))
from work w
join recording r on w.work_id = r.work_id
join release rl on rl.release_id = r.release_id
where r.is_art = 1 and r.is_vid = 0
group by w.work_id, w.name, r.recording_Id, r.name
order by w.work_id
```

Comment: That sorts October between January and February.